# Read raw binary file line by line, convert it to ascii and store it in the .txt format in the same way

Tags: python

I am able to read raw binary data line by line but can't store it line by line into a .txt file. Can someone please help me.

**Here is my code:**

```
with open("aa.dwr", "rb") as file:
  data = file.readline()
  datastring = str(data)
  while data:
    with open("out1.txt", "w") as f:
      f.write(' '.join(map(str,data)))
      f.write("\r\n")
    print("line {}: {}".format(cnt, map(str,datastring.strip())))
    data = file.readline()
    cnt +=1
```

Comment: How do you define a "line" in binary data?

Comment: you keep overwriting the same file with a new line of text (you are not appending)

Comment: If you meant that you want to split by lines in utf-8, you can just read the text, convert to utf-8 and then split lines. `s = read(f), s = s.decode(), lines = s.splitlines()`

Comment: @ selcuk when i read a line with readline(), i get ("out1.txt" [Incomplete last line] 1 line, 880 characters) and 880 characters are written in out1.txt file, and when i read it with read() command, i get ("out1.txt" [Incomplete last line] 1 line, 16616169 characters)

Comment: @lahsuk can you please elaborate, i am new to programming :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open("out1.txt", "w") as f:
    while data:
        f.write(' '.join(map(str,data)))
        f.write("\r\n")
        print("line {}: {}".format(cnt, map(str,datastring.strip())))
        data = file.readline()
        cnt +=1
```

Please try like this...

or you can try like

```
while data:
    with open("out1.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(' '.join(map(str,data)))
        f.write("\r\n")
    print("line {}: {}".format(cnt, map(str,datastring.strip())))
    data = file.readline()
    cnt +=1
```

Comment: "w" means write, if you don't do like this, you have to use "a" instead of "w".

Comment: when i use 'a' i get, ("out1.txt" 2 lines, 33232342 characters) and 33232342 characters printed in out1.txt

Comment: you used code that I posted? No changes need. That works good on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

If your original data is string encoded as binary then you can read the binary and then decode it to string. Then split the string line-by-line and write it to file.
This only applies if you want to split the text *as string* line-by-line. If you want to split binary line-by-line, like @Selcuk mentioned, what does that even mean?

```py
with open("file.b", "rb") as f:
     data = f.read()
     data = data.decode()
     lines = data.splitlines()

     with open("out.txt", "w") as f2:
         for line in lines:
             f2.write(line + "\n")
```